# R if is.na() is True then perform a function not working; the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, na, ggmap

I'm trying to use an if statement that says if a value is.na, then perform a function on a different column.

I can't get it to work, and I keep getting an error:

```
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've looked at the other questions regarding if statements, but I don't need to substitute one value for another. Instead, I need to run a function if is.na() = TRUE, and the function that I'm using (mutate_geocode) automatically makes the new columns, so I don't need to assign it to a new column. Here's what I've been trying:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)

Enrollment_Report2 <- if (is.na(Enrollment_Report$lon)) {
  mutate_geocode(facility_city)
}
```

A sample of the data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
Enrollment_Report <- tibble(facility_city = c("Atlanta", "Boston", "Tokyo"),
lon = c(NA, NA, 139.65),
lat = c(NA, NA, 35.68))
```

Comment: use `ifelse` instead of `if/else`

Comment: you should use  `if (all(is.na(Enrollment_Report$lon)))` instead ....

Comment: `if` looks at a singular value, `ifelse` takes a vector

Comment: @TPArrow, I tried that code, but all it does is give me all the columns that do not have nas.

Comment: @akrun and cory, how would I use if else? If lon is na, then I want it to do mutate_geocode on facility_city; however, if lon is anything other than na, I don't want it to do anything to the values that are there.

Answer (score 0):

We can `filter` out the NA rows and then apply the `mutate_geocode`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
Enrollment_Report %>% 
   filter(is.na(lon)) %>%
   summarise(fac_city = list(facility_city), 
            out = list(geocode(facility_city))) %>% 
   unnest %>% 
   rename(facility_city = fac_city) %>% 
   bind_rows(Enrollment_Report %>%
   filter(!is.na(lon)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# facility_city   lon   lat
#  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Atlanta       -84.4  33.7
#2 Boston        -71.1  42.4
#3 Tokyo         140.   35.7
```

---

Or create a logical index and then update the rows

```
i1 <- is.na(Enrollment_Report$lon)
Enrollment_Report[i1, -1] <- geocode(Enrollment_Report$facility_city[i1])
Enrollment_Report
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  facility_city   lon   lat
#  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Atlanta       -84.4  33.7
#2 Boston        -71.1  42.4
#3 Tokyo         140.   35.7
```

Comment: unfortunately that code yields the error: Error in data[[deparse(substitute(location))]] : subscript out of bounds. I think this is because, by default, mutate_geocode yields the longitude and latitude for the destinations and makes them into 2 distinct columns. As a result, I cannot use mutate to assign it to one column new.

Comment: @J.Sabree  Sorry for the late response.  I had to set up the API key to test it.  Can you check the update.  It seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the Google API to test, but i think this could should work:

```
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

Enrollment_Report %>% 
  mutate(geocode = if_else_(is.na(lon), geocode(facility_city), NA))
```